# Creating a Mockito test case that waits for all Schedulers.io() to complete

Tags: java, mockito, rx-java

I have a bug that manifests itself only when run in parallel, for example, on `Schedulers.io()`.  The fix was simple - to replace `flatMapCompletable` with `concatMapCompletable` to explicitly enforce sequential execution.

However, my bug reproduction unit test calls `verify()` too early because it doesn't wait for the completion.

**Important:** the function under test returns `void`, so I can't directly attach to the Observable I'm testing. I have to start that function and then wait for all threads to complete, and then check the results.

If I replace `Schedulers.io()` with `Schedulers.trampoline()`, the test executes till the end, but it fails to reproduce the issue because the code is executed on the same thread and thus doesn't cause the parallelity-specific bug.

Putting `sleep(3000);` before `verify` fixes the test, but it's an ugly solution.

How do I properly wait for all  `Schedulers.io()` threads to complete their job before calling `verify` in my test?

Here is a simplified example of the code under test with the fix commented out, so that the test fails, and the test method. In this simplified version it actually doesn't do anything with Mockito at all:

```
List<Integer> responseCompletions = new ArrayList<>();

private void methodUnderTest()
{
    Completable longCompletable = Completable.fromRunnable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Was requested for id 1");
        try {
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        System.out.println("Returning result for id 1 after long sleep");
        responseCompletions.add(1);
    })
    // must run on io() ! not main thread! otherwise test succeeds when it should actually fail
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.io());

    Completable shortCompletable = Completable.fromRunnable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Was requested for id 2");
        try {
            sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        System.out.println("Returning result for id 2 after short sleep");
        responseCompletions.add(2);
    })
    // must run on io() ! not main thread! otherwise test succeeds when it should actually fail
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.io());

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2");

    Observable.fromIterable(list)
            //.concatMapCompletable(item -> {   // <- this is the fix for the code under test
            .flatMapCompletable(item -> {

                System.out.println("Making completable for " + item);

                if (item == "1")
                    return longCompletable;
                else if (item == "2")
                    return shortCompletable;

                return Completable.complete();
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(() -> {
                        System.out.println("list done");
                    },
                    throwable -> {});
}

@Test
public void cleanedUpCompletablesSequenceExperiments() throws Exception {

    methodUnderTest();

    // would like to get rid of this ugly sleep
    // - there should be a better way to wait for waiting for it to complete?
    sleep(3000);

    assertEquals (1, (int)(responseCompletions.get(0)));
    assertEquals (2, (int)(responseCompletions.get(1)));
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some kind of MCVE of your unit test and how you setup your mocks and RX subscriptions?

Comment: @Progman  The actual code was somewhat convoluted, but I managed to create a cleaned-up simplified version, that doesn't even use mocks anymore. Still, the issue is the same - ugly `sleep` to wait for `io()` threads to complete their work.

Comment: Does the `methodUnderTest` really write to a global variable as described? If so best you can do is poll with a timeout.

If you have control over the variable it writes to, then rather than pass an `ArrayList` you could pass something like an `ArrayList` that notifies as well.

Comment: No, it actually writes to SQLite database (through a mock in the real test case). But the idea about polling would work in this case, thank you. I just hoped there is some official universal solution, some kind of `x.waitForAllThreadsToComplete`. I'm somewhat new to RxJava, so I thought maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @JustAMartin Is it an option to use the `subscribe()` overloaded method which accepts an `Action` object when the observable is completed? That way you will know that it has finished and can react on it.

Comment: This is really more of an API design problem - you're trying to test a function that is asynchronous and returns void - there's no way for a client to tell when it's finished. You should refactor the function so that it returns a `Completable`. That way your test can just subscribe to it and by notified when it's complete.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't get something right (I'm not familiar with RxJava) but from a general POV: You're using parallelization and then you assert that a list is filled in a certain sequence? From my POV this contraditcs the principle of parallelization, doesn't it? Wouldn't then `asserTrue(responseCompletions.contains(1)); asserTrue(responseCompletions.contains(2));` be a better approach?

Comment: @dano  The code under test is a bit old and messy. It is running as a background process, buried deep inside a Runnable `void run` method, which is processing a queue, and I'm testing that entire runnable as a single unit. I can't refactor `run` because it is an overriden Runnable method.

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica   The code under test was initially using `flatMapCompletable` with `Schedulers.io()`, which made it execute Completables in parallel. Corresponding to the business logic case under test, this piece of code SHOUD NOT execute in parallel, thus it should use `concatMapCompletable` instead.  That's why I first created a test that uses the original buggy parallel code and fails, and then I added the fix that makes the code NOT run in parallel, which would make those list items to be in the execution sequence order, and not in their execution time order.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) in your `methodUnderTest()`:

Add at its beginning:

```java
    private void methodUnderTest() throws InterruptedException {

        final CountDownLatch completables = new CountDownLatch(2);
```

add at the `Completable`s ends:

```java
            responseCompletions.add(1);
            completables.countDown();
```

```java
            responseCompletions.add(2);
            completables.countDown();
```

add at the end of the method:

```java
                        throwable -> {} );

        completables.await();
```

This fixes the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when removing the `sleep(3000);` but the test still fails with:

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<2>
```

Together with:

```java
        assertTrue("List responseCompletions doesn't contain 1.", responseCompletions.contains(1));
        assertTrue("List responseCompletions doesn't contain 2.", responseCompletions.contains(2));
```

as mentioned in my comment to your question the test succeeds.

Comment: It might work, if the real `methodUnderTest` wasn't buried deep in some Runnable `void run()`.  The code I provided was very simplified example of what's actually going on there. Also, `contains` wouldn't work because I actually NEED the results to be in the correct order; and not be executed in parallel. That's the reason why the test case exists - some developer made a piece of code parallel when it should have been strictly ordered.